# ReportViewer is slow on large reports despite ServerReport processing

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I have observed performance problems when rendering a 1000-page ServerReport using [Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) versions 10 and 11 in Visual Studio 2013, running against a SQL Server 2012 Report Server.

This is not a query performance problem, since the underlying stored procedure returns the data in a few seconds.  Running the report through the Report Manager returns an HTML or PDF report in 30 seconds.  It is only when the report is returned through the Report Viewer that an additional delay of several minutes is encountered.  Neither [PageCountMode.Estimate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.pagecountmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) nor local processing of the report have helped.

It appears to be a rendering issue.  This is unexpected, because the rendering should be happening on the server.  The client machines are less powerful than the server, and we do in fact want the server to render the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the rendering is in fact being done on the client, despite the fact that this is a ServerReport.

Examination of the [ExecutionLog2 view in the ReportServer database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) shows that an RPL format is returned in, e.g., 30 seconds. However, even though this is a ServerReport, the client then spends several minutes apparently performing additional rendering.  There is no additional delay for older versions of the ReportViewer, which receive HTML4.0 instead of RPL.  There is also no additional delay when all rendering is performed on the Report Server, as through the Report Manager.

It would be possible to request HTML4.0 format through [ServerReport.Render()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.serverreport_members%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), except that Render() cannot be called explicitly for a WebForms ReportViewer Control.

For large reports, it would be useful to be able to prevent the client from receiving RPL or performing any rendering.  There is a Microsoft Connect [item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/832325/request-reportviewer-serverreport-format-option) about this.